# Accept only Unicode letters, whitespaces and digits

Tags: c#, regex

I want a regular expressions to accept only only Unicode letters, whitespaces and digits.

I'm trying to use this regex, but it only removes the Arabic special character:

```cs
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"[^\u0600-\u06FF ]+", "");
```

Comment: is there any regex to remove tashkeel from Arabic character like ً   ٌ  َ

Comment: An idea to try e.g. [`[^\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{Z}]+`](https://regex101.com/r/1kFOna/1) where [`\p{M}`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) matches *a character intended to be combined with another character*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```cs
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"[^\p{L}\d\s]+", "");
```

The `[^\p{L}\d\s]+` regex matches one or more (`+`) chars other than Unicode letters (`\p{L}`), any Unicode digits (`\d`), and any Unicode whitespaces (`\s`).